# Confusing ZSH glob

Tags: zsh, glob

I am having trouble understanding the following glob:

```
${^fpath}/_git-*~(*~|*.zwc)(.N)
```

`${^fpath}` expands the `fpath` array, `(.N)` limits matches to regular files and sets the `NULL_GLOB` option. So far so good. The problem is the `_git-*~(*~|*.zwc)` part. From my understanding it starts by matching anything that begins with `_git-` and then excludes everything matching `(*~|*.zwc)`, but what exactly would that be?

Comment: Can you provide commands to create a test environment ? Like `mkdir`, `touch`ing files, setting `fpath` so one has just to copy-paste to be able to experiment. Which zsh version do you use?

Comment: @lolesque: You put me on the right track, I added the solution to my question.

Comment: You can and you should answer your own question, like if you were someone else. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @lolesque, I know, but I have to wait for at least 8 hours because my reputation is too low. Once that time is up I will move the answer where it belongs.

Comment: For somereason I've always had issues with ZSH globbing, i've never had the patience to figure it out and I seem to switch back to bash in those instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out wile trying to come up with a test environment for @lolesque.

The two `~` have different meanings. The first one excludes everything that matches the following pattern while the second one matches a literal `~`. So the pattern will match `_git-foo`, but not `_git-foo~` or `_git-foo.zwc` in any of the directories in `fpath`.